# Unmarshalling XML returns empty value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How do Unmarshall the below xml. The value of the Address tag prints empty.

Below is the xml

```
<Student>
       <address>
            <city>Andorra</city>
        </address>
<Student>
```

Below is the java code I have written. But still the value of address is empty.

```
    @XmlElement(name = "address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }

    String address;
```

Comment: What library are you using? How are you unmarshalling?

Answer (score 0):

Your jaxb bean structure is not correct :
Address should be a class enclosing a String city

```
public Address getAddress(){
   return address;
}
Address address;
```

in Address bean

```
public String getCity(){
   return city;
}
String city;
```